# rtt_ros_integration marshalling C++ linking

Tags: ros, orocos

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am currently trying to follow the [examples for orocos](https://github.com/orocos-toolchain/rtt_examples) using the [rtt_ros_integration package](https://github.com/orocos/rtt_ros_integration).

The examples were written for an old version of the **rtt ros integration** package hence I have to change a few things to get them working.

I have a problem with example **hello 2** when trying to load the marshalling service into my component in C++, my compilation outputs the following problem:

```
CMakeFiles/hello-2-properties.dir/HelloWorld.cpp.o: In function `boost::shared_ptr<RTT::Marshalling> boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<RTT::Marshalling, RTT::ServiceRequester>(boost::shared_ptr<RTT::ServiceRequester> const&)':
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:814: undefined reference to `typeinfo for RTT::Marshalling'
CMakeFiles/hello-2-properties.dir/HelloWorld.cpp.o: In function `boost::detail::sp_if_not_array<RTT::Marshalling>::type boost::make_shared<RTT::Marshalling, RTT::TaskContext*>(RTT::TaskContext* const&)':
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/make_shared_object.hpp:711: undefined reference to `RTT::Marshalling::Marshalling(RTT::TaskContext*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It looks to me that my linker cannot find some definition it needs.

Now googling for the problem what I find is the answer for the problem, but for the old version of **rtt ros integration**. The solution being to add `rtt-marshalling` to `find_package()` and `RTT-MARSHALLING_LIBRARY`to `target_link_libraries()` in the *CMakeLists.txt*.

Obviously this no longer works.

Note that the marshalling works well when loaded from script.

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216051/rtt_ros_integration-marshalling-c++-linking/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2015-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All right, I believe I have found the answer. I will explain it here as I do not find it obvious:

You should add `RTT-MARSHALLING_LIBRARY` to `target_link_libraries` in your *CMakeLists.txt*, right after `${OROCOS-RTT`. Hence a basic working version of the *CMakeLists.txt* could look like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(hello-2-properties)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS rtt_ros)

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS rtt_ros 
)

add_definitions(-DRTT_COMPONENT)
# Creates an orocos component HelloWorld
orocos_component(${PROJECT_NAME} HelloWorld.cpp) # ...you may add multiple source files
target_link_libraries(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    ${OROCOS-RTT_RTT-MARSHALLING_LIBRARY} 
    ${USE_OROCOS_LIBRARIES}
    )

# Makes this an installable/usable package for other packages.
orocos_generate_package()
```

Note that the very same problem arises when linking against the scripting service. To tackle with this, simply replace `RTT-MARSHALLING_LIBRARY` by `RTT-SCRIPTING_LIBRARY` in the above example.

Cheers,

Antoine.

---

Originally posted by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) with karma: 955 on 2015-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0